# minima and maxima of bounding box in matlab

Tags: matlab

Here is code i used for bounding box
  `propied = regionprops(L,'Area','BoundingBox','MajorAxisLength');`

Multiple bounding boxes so for loop use

```
`for n=1:size(propied,1)`

     we need to find minima and maxima for those 
     whose major axis length less than 28
     there are too many bounding boxes

    `if (propied(n).MajorAxisLength < 28)` 

         to get the bounding box of non-zero elements                       
        and  i am using 2 D image 

        `[y,x] = ind2sub(size(L), find(L));`
        `coord = [x, y];`
        `mc = min(coord)-0.5;`
        `Mc = max(coord)+0.5;`
    `end`
`end`
```

Comment: Shai can you help me?

Comment: your question is unclear. what is it **exactly** that you are trying to do?

Comment: i am trying to fine minima and maxima of bounding box and then want to draw line from minima / maxima to its uper / lower bounding box.

Comment: here is image that i am using 
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8CPKJnntTAPSHBLR2xINjVvb3M/edit

Comment: still not clear enough. Please draw **manually** (1) the point you refer to as "minima", (2) the point you refer to as "maxima", and the line you wish to draw. post this image as you did the last one so your goal would be clearer.

Comment: here is i try to explain hope its works. yellow line i want to draw

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8CPKJnntTAPZDRkSU52c3dkMjQ/edit


I have another idea, If i found Centroids whose Major Axis Length is less than 28 and then drow line from Centroids to lower or upper closest connected component. here is example

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8CPKJnntTAPWVA5Vnc2WHk1QXc/edit

Comment: please stay focused: leave the centroids out of it. What are you trying to do? are you trying to connect the [Tashkil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_diacritics) to its relevant letter?

Comment: yes i am trying to connect Tashkil (Diacritics) to its relevant letter (ligature).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are processing arabic script and trying to associate [Tashkil (Diacritics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_diacritics) to its relevant letter ([ligature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_alphabet#Ligatures)).
You assume that the `'MajorAxisLength'` property of adiacritic mark is less than 28 pixels, and you wish to associate these masks with a mask of a main letter that is not diacritic.

First, lets create two masks: one for the decorations and one for the main letters

Given this input image `BW`
[image]

```
L = bwlabel( BW ); % label each component in the text
st = regionprops( BW, 'MajorAxisLength', 'PixelIdxList', 'Centroid' );    
diac = [ st(:).MajorAxisLength ] < 28; % this is your threshold, it is not very good.
DM = zeros( size(BW) );
DM( vertcat( st(diac).PixelIdxList ) ) = 1; % mask for diacritics
```

[image]

```
LM = zeros( size(BW) );
LM( vertcat( st(~diac).PixelIdxList ) ) = 1; % mask for letters body
```

[image]

Now we'll use the centroid of each diacritic to locate the closest pixel of a ligature

```
[y x] = find( LM ); % coordinates of all ligature pixels
dc = vertcat( st(diac).Centroid ); % centroids of all diacritics
dst = sum( bsxfun( @minus, cat( 3, x, y), permute( dc, [3 1 2] ) ).^2, 3 ); % distance
[mn mi] = min( dst, [], 1 ); % closest LM pixel to each centroid
ll = L( sub2ind( size(L), y(mi), x(mi) ) ); % get the label of the closest ligature
```

Visualizing the matching results

```
ac = vertcat( st(:).Centroid ); % all centroids
figure;
imagesc( DM + 2*LM );axis image;
hold on;
plot( [dc(:,1)'; ac(ll,1)'], [dc(:,2)';ac(ll,2)'], 'r');
colormap hot
```

[image]

Note,
Using a threshold on the `'MajorAxisLength'` does not seem do to a very good job on identifying the diacritics, you might want to consider a different threshod, or thresholding the `'Area'` property instead.

Comment: Shai thank you sooooo much. i was stuck from 2 months. Thanks a lot you  solved my problem.

Comment: After finding centroids of diacritics, we check upper or lower first pixel of ligature than vertically connected to its relevant ligature. 
Like in this pic 

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8CPKJnntTAPS19td1pQSXh1X2s/edit

diacritics is linked to first white pixel of its relevant ligature.
 no luck yet, but i tried to do it.

Comment: @aish you have the `x` `y` coordinate of the closest ligature pixel stored in `x(mi) `y(mi)`. Just change the lat plot to `plot( [dc(:,1)'; x(mi)'], [dc(:,2)'; y(mi)'],'g');` you might need to play with the transpose (`'`) of `x(mi)` and `y(mi)` to make the concatenation work.